# How to get thumbnail of slideshare presentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slideshow, thumbnails

I am working on rails 3.2.13 project. I have implemented upload slideshare feature. But I need to display thumbnail(dynamic image) of uploaded slideshare. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Slideshow get API as follow. Pass the slideshow ID.

http://www.slideshare.net/developers/documentation#get_slideshow

```
Request type HTTPS GET
Authorization Optional
URL https://www.slideshare.net/api/2/get_slideshow
```

You can get the thumbnail URL in the response XML:

```
{ thumbnail URL }
```